Windows 10 to 11 migration: PC reboots back to Windows 10 again
I work with a few Windows 10 Pro computers remotely through VNC (~900 miles away) and have started Windows 11 migration attempts.  On one computer, I start the Windows 11 migration (23H2 is what it's trying to install), which appears to run fine, then when it reboots, it comes right back to Windows 10 again.  No error message is shown at any time.  Since I'm remote, I cannot see what is on the screen 100 percent of the time, so not sure if any messages are displaying during non-VNC-accessible times.
Before the migration, I've done a full Windows 10 update, have cleaned junk files, have plenty of disk space and have performed sfc /scannow.  dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth was also successfully run.  The computer in question is only a year old and Windows Update indicates it can be upgraded.  No one is available in the remote location to view the screen during the migration.

Is there any way to check in the Windows 10 logs for the reason the migration wasn't successful?
Are there any troubleshooting steps I can take beyond what I've already listed?

SetupDiag output is here: setupdiag.log
The setup log file is at: setuperr.log

Sounds like the upgrade is failing, if you start the upgrade, and you end up not being on Windows 11. Can you post the log file for the upgrade attempt? We also need a formatted log file from SetupDiag. Does your system meet any of the requirements to be blocked from upgrading to Windows 11? Which version of Windows 11, 23H2 or 24H2, check the known issues for both versions to determine if your system is purposefully upgrade blocked

That's information on how to find it. That isn't your log file, but we don't need the log file necessarily, if you provide the SetupDiag output.

@Ramhound Log files have been linked to in question

10.0.22621.4317 is 22H2, so why are you installing something that is already not supported? 10.0191206.1406 is an Insider Preview build. Are you on an Insider Preview build?

@Ramhound I did not make the choice, this is what Microsoft is pushing to this computer through Windows Update. I even downloaded the latest Windows 11 Install Assistant and it's also doing the same thing.  I am running a general release of Windows 10 and trying to install a general release version of 11.

Can you confirm what is trying to be installed? Can you confirm exactly what build you have installed? The logs suggest you absolutely do not have a GA release installed nor are you trying to upgrade to a supported version of Windows 11

@Ramhound I will have to wait a few days until I can access it again (it's not available right now).  If what you say is accurate, then HP installed a non-GA release of Windows 10, although I don't see any clue of this. Will report back next week.
